# PL/SQL group orders by date and sum the total

Tags: oracle, aggregate

I need to group orders by date and sum the total,

My table looks like this :

```
TEST_DATE
TEST_ID - NUMBER
SUCC_ID - NUMBER
```

I need to group by date and sum the total, this is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), TEST_ID, SUCC_ID
FROM MYTABS
GROUP BY TEST_DATE;
```

How can I?

thank you.

Comment: You want to sum the totals, but I can't see a total column

Answer (score 1):

You can think of aggregate queries as two parts:

- columns that are included in GROUP BY, and
- columns that are included in aggregate functions, like SUM(), MAX(), COUNT(), etc.

To put things very simply, if the column is in the SELECT clause, it has to *either* appear in the GROUP BY or inside an aggregate function.

In your case, you're probably looking for this:

```
SELECT TEST_DATE,
       COUNT(TEST_ID) AS numberOfTestID,
       SUM(SUCC_ID) AS sumOfSuccID
FROM MYTABS
GROUP BY TEST_DATE;
```

Comment: +1 , but I doubt that he is interested inthe sum of some IDs